# Using generic list, arrayList

Tags: c#, class, model-view-controller, generic-list

I want to fill in class Amount in function. I do not know how to add AmountDetail alone.
There is an error in the code I wrote. I can not list the Amount class.

```
public class Amount
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public AmountDetail AllList { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
}

public class AmountDetail
{
    public int Name{ get; set; }
    public int Surname{ get; set; }
}

public IHttpActionResult BildirimTumListeGetir(AmountDetail model)     
{
 List<AmountDetail > amountDetail = new List<AmountDetail >();       
 List<Amount> detailList= new List<Amount>();

    using (var ctx = new ktdbEntities())
    {
      var query = ctx.amountList().ToList();
      var count = query.Count;
      var total = ctx.amountListTotal(model.Id).ToList();
      model.TotalCount = total.Count();
      for(var i = 0; i<count; i++)
      {
         AmountDetail detail= new AmountDetail ();
         detail.Name= query[i].Name;
         detail.Surname= query[i].Surname;

         amountDetail.Add(detail);
      }       
    }
    detailList.Add(model);
    return Ok(detailList);
 }
```

Comment: What is the error in the code?

Comment: How can I add the amountDetail into the detailList?

Comment: I think you are not clear on your requirements. `TotalCount` is a property on `Amount` but in code you are adding that in `model` which is `AmountDetail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add all amountlist one detaillist then you can change code like that,

```
public class Amount
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public List<AmountDetail> AllList { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
}
```

otherwise you match each detailList -> amountDetail , you should master-parent id and find all linq sub query listamount and two nested for loop and add detailList.